# htaccess rewrite messing up stylesheet and no trailing slashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm such a noob when it comes to .htaccess, and can't figure this out.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tests/shop/

RewriteRule ^(recover/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ recover.php?code=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(login|register|logout|benefits|loyalty|recover)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(rs|cs|ha)/?$ game.php?game=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,L]
```

When I go to the `/recover/code/` directory as done in the 4th line, the stylesheet is completely missing due to it thinking the subdirectory is different.

This is how I include the stylesheet in my header file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">`

How can I fix this?

Also, how can I make the re-directs above all have trailing slashes? Where would I add the trailing slash to the code?

Answer (score 1):

Either change your links to be absolute urls or add a base to your page headers (between the `<head> </head>` tags).

Based on your rewrite base, I assume you'll want either something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/tests/shop/stylesheet.css">
```

or

```
<base href="/tests/shop/" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how to do the trailing slash as well (last line of my question)?

Comment: @invidious ythe regex that you have matches an optional trailing slash, I have no idea how you're generating your links but you'd need to add a trailing slash there.